# How to extract specific data has equal value for some key from NSDictionary into a combined NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

Right now i have a dictionary like this, it's just a example, i got A to Z:

```
(
        {
        id = 13;
        name = "Roll";
        firstLetter = R;
    },
        {
        id = 14;
        name = "Scroll";
        firstLetter = S;
    },
        {
        id = 16;
        name = "Rock";
        firstLetter = R;
    },
        {
        id = 17;
        name = "Start";
        firstLetter = S;
    }
)
```

I want to extract the dict has the same firstLetter and combine these into a NSArray object.   The expected results like this:

R array:

```
(
        {
        id = 13;
        name = "Roll";
        firstLetter = R;
    },
        {
        id = 16;
        name = "Rock";
        firstLetter = R;
    }
)
```

and S array:

```
(

    {
        id = 14;
        name = "Scroll";
        firstLetter = S;
    },
        {
        id = 17;
        name = "Start";
        firstLetter = S;
    }
)
```

How to do that?

Comment: create a mutable dictionay & do a "First Letter" -> "NSMutableArray"  map

Comment: @adali and How to do that?

Comment: i put my answer below :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the better method would be the one suggested by [Saohooou](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17226652/767730)

But it can be optimised as

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"id": @13,@"name":@"Roll",@"firstLetter":@"R"},
                   @{@"id": @14,@"name":@"Scroll",@"firstLetter":@"S"},
                   @{@"id": @15,@"name":@"Rock",@"firstLetter":@"R"},
                   @{@"id": @16,@"name":@"Start",@"firstLetter":@"S"}];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *dict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *key = dict[@"firstLetter"];
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = dictionary[key];
    if (!tempArray) {
        tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    [tempArray addObject:dict];
    dictionary[key] = tempArray;
}];
NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    NSMutableDictionay *dic = [NSMutableDictionay dictionay];
                    for ( YourObject *obj in yourDic.allValues )
                    {

                        NSMutableArray *dateArray = dic[obj.firstLetter];
                        if ( !dateArray )
                        {
                            dateArray = [NSMutableArray array];

                            [dic setObject:dateArray forKey:obj.firstLetter];
                        }

                        [dateArray addObject:obj];
                    }
```

so **dic** is what you want

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 NSString *currentStr;
 //this int is to detect currentStr
 NSInteger i;

 NSMutableArray* R_Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 NSMutableArray* S_Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


 for (NSDictionary *myDict in MyDictArray){

    NSString *tempStr = [myDict objectForKey:@"firstLetter"];
    if(currentStr = nil && [currentStr isEqualToString:""]){
       currentStr = tempStr;

       if([currentStr isEqualToString:"R"] ){
          [R_Array addObject:myDict];
          i = 0;
       }else{
          [S_Array addObject:myDict];
          i = 1;
       }
    }else{
       if([currentStr isEqualToString:tempStr]){
          (i=0)?[R_Array addObject:myDict]:[S_Array addObject:myDict];
       }else{
          (i=0)?[R_Array addObject:myDict]:[S_Array addObject:myDict];
       }
    }

 }
```

Base on your dictionaries. There are only two type, so i just created two array and use if-else for solving the problem. if there are multy values, you can try switch-case to do it.

Lets do this

```
  NSMutaleDictionary * speDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  for(i=0;i<26;i++){
     switch (i){
            case 0:
                [speDict setObject:[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"A"];
                break;
            case 1:
                [speDict setObject:[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"B"];
                break;
            Case 2:
                [speDict setObject:[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"C"];
                break;
            ...........
            Case 25:
                [speDict setObject:[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"Z"];
                break;
        }
  }

  for (NSDictionary *myDict in MyDictArray){

     NSString *tempStr = [myDict objectForKey:@"firstLetter"];

     switch (tempStr)
            case A:
                [self addToMySpeDictArrayWithObject:myDict andStr:temStr];
                break;
            case B:
                [self addToMySpeDictArrayWithObject:myDict andStr:temStr];
                break;
            Case C:
                [self addToMySpeDictArrayWithObject:myDict andStr:temStr];
                break;
            ...........
            Case Z:
                [self addToMySpeDictArrayWithObject:myDict andStr:temStr];
                break;
  }

  -(void)addToMySpeDictArrayWithObject:(NSDictionary*)_dict andStr:(NString*)_str
  {
       NSMutableArray *tempArray = [speDict objectForKey:_str];
       [tempArray addObject:_dict];

  }
```

then the speDict is like

```
 A:
 //all firstletter is A
 myDict
 myDict
 myDict
 B:
 //all firstletter is B
 myDict
 myDict
 .......
```

Comment: No, it's just a example. I got all the letters from A to Z.

Comment: then you can use switch-case instead of if-else just like `switch(tempStr)  case A:  [A_array addObject:]; break;  case B: .........`

Comment: sorry i made a mistake, but i've fixed now

Comment: My code is not perfect, i sugest you can try to check wheather your speDict has the firstLetter array or not, if it doesn't have then creat a new one and add the wanted object to that array. Using this method, then you dont have to create 26 array at the first time. Because you don't know wheather the array you created would be used or not, if it is unused, then it will cause memory waste.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you organized the dict as an NSArray.

```
NSMutableDictionary* result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; // NSDictionary of NSArray
for (id entry in dict) {
    NSString* firstLetter = [entry firstLetter];

    // Find the group of firstLetter 
    NSMutableArray* group = result[firstLetter];
    if (group == nil) {
        // No such group --> create new a new one and add it to the result
        group = [NSMutableArray array];
        result[firstLetter] = group;
    }

    // Either group has existed, or has been just created
    // Add the entry to it
    [group addObject: entry];
}
```

`result` holds what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the sample you've provided is an array of dicts (not a dict as the question notes). Now, the easiest way to query this array is by using an `NSPredicate`. Something like this perhaps:

```
NSArray *objects = ...; // The array with dicts

NSString *letter = @"S"; // The letter we want to pull out
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstLetter == %@", letter];

NSArray *s = [objects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p]; // All the 'S' dicts
```

If for some reason you need to group all of your objects without having to ask for a specific letter each time, you could try something like this:

```
// Grab all available firstLetters
NSSet *letters = [NSSet setWithArray:[objects valueForKey:@"firstLetter"]];

for (NSString *letter in letters)
{
    NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstLetter == %@", letter];
    NSArray *x = [objects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
    // Do something with 'x' 
    // For example append it on a mutable array, or set it as the object
    // for the key 'letter' on a mutable dict
}
```

And of course you could further optimize this approach by implementing a method for filtering the array based on a letter. I hope that this makes sense.